# Check Empty Fields in HTML form and show message box if there is an empty field/s

Tags: php, html, webforms

im working on a project about a web-based system. I have a form, i want to check if all the fields are filled in but when one of the fields is empty it will show a prompt and will not record the data to the database unless the form have been completed. I am able to show a prompt if the fields is empty but still, it records the data provided even if one or some of the filled is empty.

Here is my html form code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg){
if(elem.value.length == 0){
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
FNAME: <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="50" id="required"/>
MNAME: <input type="text" name="mname" maxlength="50" id="required"/>
LNAME: <input type="text" name="lname" maxlength="50" id="required"/><br/>

Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /><br/>
Female <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><br/>

College: 
<select name="college">
<option value="default"> --- </option>
<option value="CEC">CEC</option>
<option value="CAD">CAD</option>
<option value="COB">COB</option>
</select>
</br>

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit"    onclick="notEmpty(document.getElementById('required'), 'Please Enter a Value')"
value='SUBMIT'/>
</form>
```

my php code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","abs","abs");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO name (fname, mname, lname, gender, college)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[mname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[college]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

I can't get it to work. I am new at php. please help me. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You should use unique id attributes for each each of your inputs.

Comment: never insert user provided data directly in to the db.

Comment: Instead of `id="required"`, why don't you use `required="required"`?

Comment: @kcire arraveug: Why you not accepted any of answer for questions asked by you ? Even you doing "Thanks for help to all :)" . Please accept if that helped you.

Comment: @Teez im sorry sir. im just new in this. i do not know that there is something like that. im so sorry. thanks to you. now i know how. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something wrong in your code. You are passing one element's id and want to check all elements.
Also Id of all fields is same.

Suggesting you a link : http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/formrequired.shtml

showing a live example what you want. You can take code from here and try.

Comment: Why you not accepted any of answer for questions asked by you ? Even you doing "Thanks for help to all :)"

Comment: im sorry sir. im just new in this. i do not know that there is something like that. im so sorry. thanks to you. now i know how. :)

i also tried this one. how can i apply this to dropdowns and radio buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning a value but you are not using it.

`onclick="return notEmpty(...`

A false return value will stop the submit.

This is the reason the form still gets submitted to the backend.

In addition, `id` should always be unique.  Using `getElementById` will only return you a single element so you are not actually checking all of your required fields.  You could instead assign a class of required and loop over the elements.

Comment: You should mention his function will only ever check a single input field since there are multiple fields with that ID, thus allowing the others to remain empty (undesired).

Comment: @animuson okay, I'll add that.  Had left it out since it had already been pointed out (sort of).  But I guess it is best to have in the answer.